# How to get Vim to start NERDTree on startup, if no input is given on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, vim

I have `gvim-gtk2` installed from my own Open Build Service repo ([here](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/home:fusion809/gvim-gtk2) it is) and most things work fine with it. The only exception is that my `~/.vimrc` is meant to load NERDTree on startup, when no input is given (i.e., it's started as `vim` or `gvim` with no file or folder specified to open) and it isn't.

Rather this is the screen Vim shows on startup:
[image]

[Here](https://github.com/fusion809/vim/raw/master/.vimrc) is my `~/.vimrc` file. Here are the lines in my `~/.vimrc` that are meant to start NERDTree on Vim startup:

```
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif
```

these lines are borrowed from the [NERDTree README](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/README.markdown#faq) file. On other distros I find this line in my `~/.vimrc` loads NERDTree on startup exactly the way I want it to but on Arch Linux it isn't. The `/etc/vimrc` file my `vim-runtime` package installs is:

```
" All system-wide defaults are set in $VIMRUNTIME/archlinux.vim (usually just
" /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/archlinux.vim) and sourced by the call to :runtime
" you can find below.  If you wish to change any of those settings, you should
" do it in this file (/etc/vimrc), since archlinux.vim will be overwritten
" everytime an upgrade of the vim packages is performed.  It is recommended to
" make changes after sourcing archlinux.vim since it alters the value of the
" 'compatible' option.

" This line should not be removed as it ensures that various options are
" properly set to work with the Vim-related packages.
runtime! archlinux.vim

" If you prefer the old-style vim functionalty, add 'runtime! vimrc_example.vim'
" Or better yet, read /usr/share/vim/vim80/vimrc_example.vim or the vim manual
" and configure vim to your own liking!

" do not load defaults if ~/.vimrc is missing
"let skip_defaults_vim=1
```

and here is my `archlinux.vim` file:

```
" The ArchLinux global vimrc - setting only a few sane defaults
"
" Maintainer:      Thomas Dziedzic [gostrc@gmail.com]
"
" NEVER EDIT THIS FILE, IT'S OVERWRITTEN UPON UPGRADES, GLOBAL CONFIGURATION
" SHALL BE DONE IN /etc/vimrc, USER SPECIFIC CONFIGURATION IN ~/.vimrc

" Normally we use vim-extensions. If you want true vi-compatibility
" remove change the following statements
set nocompatible                " Use Vim defaults instead of 100% vi compatibility
set backspace=indent,eol,start  " more powerful backspacing

" Now we set some defaults for the editor
set history=50                  " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler                       " show the cursor position all the time

" Suffixes that get lower priority when doing tab completion for filenames.
" These are files we are not likely to want to edit or read.
set suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc,.png,.jpg

if has('gui_running')
  " Make shift-insert work like in Xterm
  map <S-Insert> <MiddleMouse>
  map! <S-Insert> <MiddleMouse>
endif
```

Comment: OP filed an [issue](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/685) in the nerdtree tracker

Comment: NERDTree has defaults not meeting expectations of those from Visual Studio world. Nothing works as expected. DIY product, as most of OSS.
Here’s my $500 spent .vimrc for NERDTree: https://gist.github.com/avesus/1954d9384d86cc1e39cb2b2eff7017b7